# Not able to add distributor while configuring transactional replication

Tags: transactional-replication

I need to setup transactional replication, the publisher is SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition and the distributor is SQL Server 2017 Standard edition. I am trying to add the distributor, from the distributor configuration wizard when I try to connect to the distributor, it fails saying- `"SQL server could not retrieve information about server 'SERVER NAME', Could not find stored procedure sp_MSreplcheck_qv Error: 2812"`. However we have been able to add this distributor for other publication servers. I found a site where people has mentioned the solution for it but that doesn't work for me. I have been exploring Google but not able to find the solution. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using an older version of SSMS, I switched to a newer version and I was able to add the distributor successfully.